# Why WPF DatePicker validation error happens in different cultures

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, datepicker

Good day.

I try to run app under Win8.1 En and DatePicker works without validation errors when e.g. (mm/dd/yyy) 10/20/2016 selected.

Then i try to run this app under Win8.1 Ru. When (dd.mm.yyyy) 20.10.2016 selected, happens validation error for DatePicker.

Why it should be?

If i add in App.xaml.cs in App() constructor

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

it works great, 'cause it always in en-US culture. But why i have validation error for russian culture?

Comment: It seems that culture is not set for russian version (there are no 20 months). Are you sure, you put `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");` for russian version?

Comment: @Fka error too. But if i set `Language="ru-RU"` for DatePicker, all is great. But it bad solution if i need more than one locale

Comment: that's charm of supporting more than one locale.

Comment: @Fka yep, but it's really charm. Similar solution - one locale, but it's not best solution for me

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue just a week ago. The best way to handle the problem is manually save the date and set from one format. Alternatively you can force them to use en-us culture to do all thing same on other region settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check for current thread's UI culture, not just current thread's culture.

Or on the main Frame of your WPF, set the UI culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```